# Cannot read property 'X' of undefined - React-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am getting my feet wet in React.js and find it a bit tough with all the syntax and different ways of thinking about stuff.  I am trying to create a Modal interface for my webapp and I've done this so far:

**MyModal.jsx**

```
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ButtonToolbar from 'react-bootstrap';
import React from 'react';

export default class MyModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {show: false};
    }

    showModal() {
        this.setState({show: true});
    }

    hideModal() {
        this.setState({show: false});
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ButtonToolbar>
          <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
            Launch demo modal
          </Button>

          <Modal
            {...this.props}
            show={this.state.show}
            onHide={this.hideModal}
            dialogClassName="custom-modal"
          >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">Modal heading</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <h4>Wrapped Text</h4>
              <p>Blah</p>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button onClick={this.hideModal}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        </ButtonToolbar>
        );
    } // end render function

} // end export default
```

However, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Header' of undefined
MyModal.render
webpack:///./src/components/MyModal.jsx?:68:37
```

I'm guessing that it's the `Modal.Header` thing that's causing problems but when I've already imported `Modal` so I assume that imports everything within it.  I even tried `import Modal.Header from 'react-bootstrap'` and that line errored out so that's not the way to go.

What is weird is that it's saying the error is on line 68 when `MyModal.jsx` is only 48 lines.  In any case, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap';
```

to:

```
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 2):

You are importing `Model` in a wrong way.

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
// or
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Same with `Modal`, from [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html) spec